# How pass id from client to webform using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

My code doesn't work, I do not know why.

My ajax code call:

```
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id")
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "XTM307.aspx/GetPart",
        data: { "id": id },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

        }
    });
```

My server code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Sub GetPart(id As String)
    Dim test = 2
    test += 3
End Sub
```

Comment: I put break point at test += 3, but the code never jump to that point

Comment: You are using UseHttpGet:=True in webservice attribute and sending request type POST in Ajax code

Comment: I try to convert tye to GET but it still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webservice method is `GET`, so the  ajax call should be like:

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id")

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "XTM307.aspx/GetPart?id=" + id,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```